# Able to ping IP-8.8.8.8 but not DNS- google.com, after sharing wifi internet connection with Raspberry Pi 2 - MODB through LAN (Headless mode)

Tags: raspbian, raspi-config

I just started using raspberry pi.I am trying to sharing wifi internet connection with Raspberry Pi 2 - MODB through LAN (Headless mode)

**What I have done so far?**

1. Flashed SD card with 2015-05-05-raspbian-wheezy image
2. Enable “Allow other network users to connect through this computer‘s Internet connection” option for Wireless Network Connection Properties.
3. Append ip=Fixed IP:: Lan IP in cmdline.txt file
4. Open SSH with Fixed IP on PUTTY.

**Issue:**

Now through SSH, I am able to ping 8.8.8.8 IP which means I got internet access to my raspberry module. But not able to ping DNS - http://google.com, getting error `unknown host`. And also not able to perform and updates, getting error `Failed to fetch http://___`

Getting confused whether  raspberry board got internet access or not. And if yes, then why not able to access DNS and updates.

**Outputs:**

1. **Command prompt**

**C:\Users\Harish>ipconfig**

```
Windows IP Configuration

Wireless LAN adapter Wireless Network Connection:

Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :

   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::51c4:e1df:75:72f8%14


   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.0.111

   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0

   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.0.1
Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :

   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::1939:628b:ec79:f8a9%13

   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.137.1

   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0

   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :
```

**C:\Users\Harish>arp -a**

```
Interface: 192.168.137.1 --- 0xd

  Internet Address      Physical Address      Type

  192.168.137.4         b8-27-eb-1f-05-15     dynamic

  192.168.137.255       ff-ff-ff-ff-ff-ff     static

  224.0.0.2             01-00-5e-00-00-02     static

  224.0.0.22            01-00-5e-00-00-16     static

  224.0.0.252           01-00-5e-00-00-fc     static

  239.255.255.250       01-00-5e-7f-ff-fa     static

  255.255.255.255       ff-ff-ff-ff-ff-ff     static

Interface: 192.168.0.111 --- 0xe

  Internet Address      Physical Address      Type

  192.168.0.1           14-cc-20-f5-cb-ba     dynamic

  192.168.0.103         08-ed-b9-d1-c3-f5     dynamic

  192.168.0.107         48-d2-24-c4-0f-f0     dynamic

  192.168.0.110         8c-a9-82-5d-8b-ac     dynamic

  192.168.0.255         ff-ff-ff-ff-ff-ff     static

  224.0.0.2             01-00-5e-00-00-02     static

  224.0.0.22            01-00-5e-00-00-16     static

  224.0.0.252           01-00-5e-00-00-fc     static

  239.255.255.250       01-00-5e-7f-ff-fa     static

  255.255.255.255       ff-ff-ff-ff-ff-ff     static
```

Also able to ping LAN and FIXED ip through command prompt.

**2. SSH output**

**pi@raspberrypi  ~ $ sudo cat /etc/network/interfaces**

```
auto io

inface lo inet loopback


auto eth0

allow-hotplug etho

inface eth0 inet manual


auto wlan)

allow-hotplug wloan0

inface wlan0 inet manual

wpa-conf /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf


auto wlan1

allow-hotplug wlan1

inface wlan1 inet manual

wpa-conf /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
```

**pi@raspberrypi  ~ $ ifconfig**

```
eth0 Link encap:Ethernet HWaddr b8:27:eb:a8:cf:a4

inet addr:192.168.137.4 Bcast:192.168.137.255 Mask:255.255.255.0

UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST MTU:1500 Metric:1

RX packets:795 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0

TX packets:814 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0

collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000

RX bytes:61996 (60.5 KiB) TX bytes:114753 (112.0 KiB)


lo Link encap:Local Loopback

inet addr:127.0.0.1 Mask:255.0.0.0

UP LOOPBACK RUNNING MTU:65536 Metric:1

RX packets:308 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0

TX packets:308 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0

collisions:0 txqueuelen:0

RX bytes:24856 (24.2 KiB) TX bytes:24856 (24.2 KiB)
```

**root@raspberrypi:/home/pi# route –n**

```
Kernel IP routing table

Destination         Gateway            Genmask         Flags  Metric Ref    Use 
Iface

0.0.0.0             192.168.137.1   0.0.0.0              UG    0      0        0 eth0

192.168.137.0       0.0.0.0               255.255.255.0   U      0      0        0 eth0
```

I also tried after modifying interface file, but still not able to ping DNS.

**pi@raspberrypi  ~ $ sudo cat /etc/network/interfaces**

```
auto io

inface lo inet loopback


auto eth0

allow-hotplug etho

inface eth0 inet dhcp

address 192.168.137.4

netmask 255.255.255.0

network 192.168.137.0

broadcast 192.168.137.255

gateway 192.168.137.1


auto wlan)

allow-hotplug wloan0

inface wlan0 inet manual

wpa-conf /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf


auto wlan1

allow-hotplug wlan1

inface wlan1 inet manual

wpa-conf /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
```

Comment: It is unclear from your question what the physical connections are. You also need to tell us what Raspbian you are using - unfortunately the latest changed how internet works. /etc/network/interfaces has lots of obvious typos.

Comment: give us output of `cat /etc/resolv.conf`

Comment: My issue is resolved. Thanks to point out resolv.conf file. I searched few things, appended resolv.conf file with
“dns-nameserver 192.168.137.1
nameserver 8.8.8.8”
and it worked but not sure how. Can you tell how it worked? What’s the effect of adding gateway IP to resolv.conf file?

Comment: `nameserver 8.8.8.8` line should be sufficient. This file configures the DNS server(s) for the system hence failing to resolve domain names when was not configured.

Comment: When using DHCP to assign IP-number you also get your DNS-servers.  If you use Fixed IP you need to set everything yourself.

Answer (score 3):

Add this line to /etc/network/interfaces under wlan interface sections.( in your raspberry pi)

```
nameserver 8.8.8.8
```